# How to find same classes in a list with one different value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Privileges. A Privilege class has four properties: Type, AccessType, Value and Action.
I want to throw an exception if there are multiple Privileges where the Type, AccessType and Value are the same, BUT the Actions are different.

So for example a list of p1 and p2 would throw an exception:

```
Privilege p1 = new Privilege{Type = "a", AccessType = "a", Value = "a", Action = "a"};
Privilege p2 = new Privilege{Type = "a", AccessType = "a", Value = "a", Action = "b"};
```

I would like to use LINQ, but not sure how.

Comment: why to use LINQ and not override Equals?

Comment: this will not really throw an exception but you can do something like this:

if(privileges.Contains(x => !(x.Type == p1.Type && x.AccessType..)
{
privileges.Add(p1);
}

it will not throw but you wont let the case happen

Comment: @AsfK Equals is already overridden, and I use that for a different problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to allow duplicate type+access-type+value but only if the action is also the same?

```
bool throwException = pList
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Type, x.AccessType, x.Value })
    .Any(g => g.Select(p => p.Action).Distinct().Count() > 1);
```

First i'm building groups of these three properties. Then i check if any of these groups contains multiple actions. Then you can throw the exception.

A small optimization might be(if the duplicate lists are large) if you replace

```
Distinct().Count() > 1
```

with

```
Distinct().Skip(1).Any()
```

Comment: @Florian: thanks for the fiddle, you're right. I've reworked it now: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a1DqsP

Comment: Any reason for using `Select` separately rather than using a `GroupBy` overload that selects `p.Action`? (See my answer as an example.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton: your approach is abosulutely fine. Actually i always forget the `GroupBy` overload because you can always achieve the same without :)

Comment: This includes access to the whole list each iteration with g.Select(p => p.Action).Distinct().Count(). And it's also a very complicated approach for a simple problem.

Comment: @Chriz: I don't understand your objection. `Select` doesn't access "the whole list". Just of the duplicate-group. I have added a small optimization.

Comment: @Tim `.Distinct()` enumerates the whole list and `.Count()` reads all elements as well. Both operations require the full list to be read.

Comment: @Tim : yes it doesn't work with objects because reference won't be the same, you need indeed to select the object property value. my bad :-(

Comment: @Chriz: No, `Distinct` just enumerates the current `Action`-group and `Count` just counts the duplicate actions of this group.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to group by `Type`, `AccessType` and `Value` (which you can do with an anonymous type) and then check the actions. Assuming it's okay to have values where the `Action` is the *same* in each case, you could write code like this:

```
// Normally I'd expect you to have some kind of sequence of privileges rather
// than separate variables.
var privileges = new[] { p1, p2 };
var failures = privileges
    // Group the privileges by 3 properties, extracting actions as the values
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.Type, p.AccessType, p.Value }, p => p.Action)
    // Find any groups which have more than one distinct action
    .Where(g => g.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
    .ToList();

if (failures.Count > 0)
{
    // There's at least one failure. There may be many. Throw
    // whatever exception you want here. This is just an example.
    var individualMessages =
        failures.Select(g => $"{g.Key}: {string.Join(", ", g.Distinct())}");
    throw new Exception(
        $"Invalid privilege combinations: {string.Join("; ", individualMessages})");
}
```

Here's a complete example showing a couple of failures:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Privilege
{
    public string Type { get; }
    public string AccessType { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
    public string Action { get; }

    public Privilege(string type, string accessType, string value, string action)
    {
        Type = type;
        AccessType = accessType;
        Value = value;
        Action = action;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var privileges = new List<Privilege>
        {
            // Bad: should cause an exception
            new Privilege("a", "a", "a", "a"),
            new Privilege("a", "a", "a", "b"),

            // Another bad one; let's check the
            // failure represents both
            new Privilege("x", "y", "z", "action1"),
            new Privilege("x", "y", "z", "action2"),

            // These have one property difference
            // in each case
            new Privilege("b", "a", "a", "a"),
            new Privilege("a", "b", "a", "a"),
            new Privilege("a", "a", "b", "a"),

            // Duplicate type/access/value, but same action too.
            new Privilege("d", "e", "f", "action"),
            new Privilege("d", "e", "f", "action")
        };
        CheckPrivileges(privileges);
    }

    static void CheckPrivileges(IEnumerable<Privilege> privileges)
    {
        var failures = privileges
            // Group the privileges by 3 properties, extracting actions as the values
            .GroupBy(p => new { p.Type, p.AccessType, p.Value }, p => p.Action)
            // Find any groups which have more than one distinct action
            .Where(g => g.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Count > 0)
        {
            // There's at least one failure. There may be many. Throw
            // whatever exception you want here. This is just an example.
            var individualMessages =
                failures.Select(g => $"{g.Key}: {string.Join(", ", g.Distinct())}");
            throw new Exception(
                $"Invalid privilege combinations: {string.Join("; ", individualMessages)}");
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an exception like this (I've added the line breaks):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Invalid privilege combinations:
{ Type = a, AccessType = a, Value = a }: a, b;
{ Type = x, AccessType = y, Value = z }: action1, action2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplicates = privilegecollection.GroupBy(x => new {x.Type, x.AccessType, x.Value})
                                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

If `duplicates` count is greater than 0 then you can throw exception.

Comment: That's not correct. OP wants duplicates, but these duplicates must all have the same action.

Comment: No he said `BUT the Actions are different`.

Comment: Exactly - an exception should be thrown *because* the actions are different. I read this the same way as Tim: if the actions are the same, that's okay. (See my answer for a complete example showing this.)

Comment: Yes, it's only exceptional if the actions are different. _"I want to throw an exception if there are multiple Privileges where the Type, AccessType and Value are the same, BUT the Actions are different"_

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple solution here ist using 2 `Any()`s.

```
bool HasDoubleOtherAction = privilegeList.Any(outer => privilegeList
                               .Any(inner => outer.Type == inner.Type
                                             && outer.AccessType == inner.AccessType
                                             && outer.Value == inner.Value
                                             && outer.Action != inner.Action));
```

Comment: You even enumerate the list once for every privilege in it if there's no exceptional state, but you are complaining about my GroupBy approach :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess we'd have to make a performance test which solution is faster in which cases :) . Too much efford for too less result.

Comment: feel free to build large sample lists. But consider that throwing an exception is an exceptional state which should happen very rarely (if at all). So you can't presume it. The normal state will be that the large list will not contain different actions per group. In that case you will check every privilege and every privilege will again be compared with every other privilege.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right, the "ExceptionalState" makes the difference. In a normal succeeding case you need to check all Elements every time and the benefit of the possible hit on early elements vanishes.

Comment: Even then i don't need to check "all elements every time". I also use `Any`, so if the first group already contains an invalid state, it will stop processing immediately. Also, both, `GroupBy` and `Distinct`, are implemented using a set based approach and are pretty efficient.